# can an "_inout" parameter be "const" "?

Tags: c, sal

My understanding is that if a pointer points to something that is read and written, that is, "*inout*" then, by definition it cannot be "const" (because of "out") yet, there are prototypes in the C headers that specify parameters as "*inout* const" which doesn't make sense to me.  For intance:

`EXTERN_C _Check_return_ NTSTATUS APIENTRY D3DKMTEnumAdapters2(_Inout_ CONST D3DKMT_ENUMADAPTERS2*);`

As I mentioned above, I don't see how the parameter can be "const" given that it's also "out".

Am I misunderstanding something or is that definition incorrect ?

Thank you for your help.

`

Comment: The pointed-to-value is const, not the pointer itself.
this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143262/what-is-the-difference-between-const-int-const-int-const-and-int-const

Comment: @Raildex, now that you mention it, I'd read that as specifying that the pointer is constant but what it points to is "inout".

Comment: @Raildex true, but the pointer itself cannot be modified inside the function as it is passed by value.

Comment: Looks like an error in the documentation and/or header, to me, because the `NumAdapters` member of the passed (pointed-to) structure **is modified** by the function.

Comment: @AdrianMole that's what I think too.  The structure is modified (inout), therefore it cannot be "const"

Comment: @ScienceAmateur: The fact that a parameter is a pointer to a `const` object does not mean the function may not or cannot modify the object. The `const` qualifier was a late addition to C and serves as little more than advice and an aid against accidental modifications. If an object was originally defined with `const`, then a function may cast a `const` pointer to it to a non-`const` pointer to it and use the new pointer to modify the object, and this behavior is defined by the C standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory, there is nothing to prevent an argument declared as `_Inout_` having the `const` qualifier, when that argument is a pointer to a structure.

For instance, the  argument in the call to `D3DKMTEnumAdapters2` is a pointer to a `D3DKMT_ENUMADAPTERS2` structure, which is defined as follows:

```c
typedef struct _D3DKMT_ENUMADAPTERS2 {
  ULONG              NumAdapters;
  D3DKMT_ADAPTERINFO *pAdapters;
} D3DKMT_ENUMADAPTERS2;
```

Now, if the `pAdapters` member were a pre-allocated array of `D3DKMT_ADAPTERINFO` objects (of size specified in the `NumAdapters` member), and **all the function did** was to fill that data array with the relevant information for each adapter, then the passed structure *itself* would not have been modified – so there is no conflict with the `const` qualifier on the argument.

However, from the [documentation for `D3DKMTEnumAdapters2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/d3dkmthk/nf-d3dkmthk-d3dkmtenumadapters2), it appears that the `NumAdapers` member itself is also changed (potentially):

> When D3DKMT_ENUMADAPTERS2::pAdapters is null,
> D3DKMT_ENUMADAPTERS2::NumAdapters is set to the maximum supported
> adapter count. Callees will commonly invoke the method, first, to
> retrieve the maximum supported adapter count.

Thus, according to that paragraph, the `const` attribute will be violated when the function is called with a `NULL` value for the `pAdapters` member of the passed (pointed-to) structure.

---

Note that the linked documentation also *implies* that the `NumAdapters` member is modified, even when a non-null `pAdapters` value is given (emphasis mine):

> Caller passes in array size and empty array space. Callee verifies
> enough room in the array, fills out array, ***and passes back how much
> of the array was used***.

Comment: Thank you Adrian. Everything you mentioned about the number of adapters potentially being changed is what I saw as a conflict with the "const" specifier.  IOW, I think that for that function, the "const" is not "appropriate" (to put it that way)